# How to exclude files in a custom clean task?

Tags: sbt

I'm working on a custom `TaskKey` that makes a `clean` that keeps a folder in `target` directory - it's a database that I don't want to fill everytime.

So I tried something like that:

```
lazy val cleanOutput = taskKey[Unit]("Prints 'Hello World'")

cleanOutput := clean.value

cleanKeepFiles in cleanOutput <+= target { target => target / "database" }
```

It seems that the statement `in cleanOutput` is not taken in consideration.
Even when I do just the following it doesn't work:

```
cleanKeepFiles in clean <+= target { target => target / "database" }
```

But the following works:

```
cleanKeepFiles <+= target { target => target / "database" }
```

Why is the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are *keys*, which may have defined values in different *scopes* (project, configuration or task).

A key can be defined, even if it's not used in any scope, as well as a key can be given a value in any scope. The later doesn't mean that the value will be used by a specific task. It means you can *reuse* keys declared by sbt for your purposes.

What you do you declare a new `taskKey`. You define your task to call `clean`. You then define `cleanKeepFiles` in the *scope* of your new task to equal to whatever the value was before, plus your database directory in the target.

The value is set correctly, but the `clean` task will not look for it in the scope of your task.

You can verify it:

```
> show cleanOutput::cleanKeepFiles  
[info] List(/home/lpiepiora/Desktop/sbt/stack-overflow/q-24020437/target/.history, /home/lpiepiora/Desktop/sbt/stack-overflow/q-24020437/target/database)
```

Additionally you can check:

```
> inspect *:cleanKeepFiles
[info] Setting: scala.collection.Seq[java.io.File] = List(/home/lpiepiora/Desktop/sbt/stack-overflow/q-24020437/target/.history)
[info] Description:
[info]  Files to keep during a clean.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/home/lpiepiora/Desktop/sbt/stack-overflow/q-24020437/}q-24020437/*:cleanKeepFiles
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbt.Defaults) Defaults.scala:278
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  *:history
[info] Reverse dependencies:
[info]  *:clean
[info] Delegates:
[info]  *:cleanKeepFiles
[info]  {.}/*:cleanKeepFiles
[info]  */*:cleanKeepFiles
[info] Related:
[info]  *:cleanOutput::cleanKeepFiles
```

You can also see that sbt knows, that you have set it in the scope `*:cleanOutput::cleanKeepFiles`, it is just not using it.

Where it will look for it?. You can check it by *inspecting* the `clean` task.

```
> inspect clean
[info] Task: Unit
[info] Description:
[info]  Deletes files produced by the build, such as generated sources, compiled classes, and task caches.
// next lines are important
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  *:cleanKeepFiles
[info]  *:cleanFiles
```

You can see that one of the dependencies is `*:cleanKeepFiles`, the `*` means Global configuration. This means that the `clean` task will look for the setting in that scope. You can change your setting to:

```
cleanKeepFiles += target.value / "database"
```

This will set it in the correct scope used by the `clean` task.

### Edit

There is a [doClean](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/sxr/sbt/Defaults.scala.html#sbt.Defaults.doClean) function which you can reuse. Given that, you can define your clean task like this:

```
val cleanKeepDb = taskKey[Unit]("Cleans folders keeping database")

cleanKeepDb := Defaults.doClean(cleanFiles.value, (cleanKeepFiles in cleanKeepDb).value)

cleanKeepFiles in cleanKeepDb += target.value / "database"
```

Comment: Good explanation but if I do that I modify the behaviour of `clean` and I wanted to have a custom clean that ignore `database` folder and keep the current `clean` task as it is.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the way how you can do it.

Comment: This is dramatically better than what I did. Cheers @lpiepiora!