# How to execute shell command before compile task?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'd like to execute a shell command - `rm -r` a directory - whenever my sbt project builds. This would be before `compile`.

Reasoning: There's a cache file that never gets updated. If I delete it before each compile, it forces the update.

Please advise.

Comment: Yes. I upvoted it for clarity, and just marked it as answered after verifying functionality as well. Exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create a task that deletes the file:

```
val removeCacheTask = TaskKey[Unit]("removeCacheFile", "Deletes a cache file")
val removeCacheSettings = removeCacheTask := {
    import sys.process._
    Seq("rm", "/path/to/file") !
}
```

Then require that the task be run before compilation by adding these settings to your project:

```
Project(...).settings(
    removeCacheSettings,
    compile in Compile <<= (compile in Compile).dependsOn(removeCacheTask)
)
```

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/4DMWSTNM4kQ

---

In `build.sbt` it would look like this:

```
lazy val removeCacheTask = TaskKey[Unit]("removeCacheFile", "Deletes a cache file")

removeCacheTask := {
    import sys.process._
    Seq("rm", "/path/to/file")!
}

compile in Compile <<= (compile in Compile).dependsOn(removeCacheTask)
```

Comment: Note that if you want to reference the task in a subproject, you must give a scope or the task will not be found in the subproject. Easiest way to write is `removeCacheTask in Global := { ... }`

Comment: As of sbt `1.1.1`, this approach now works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44669226/1080804

Answer (score 6):

[@LimbSoup answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24174752/1305344) is fine, but there're some improvements to consider.

The command to execute `rm` might not be available on other non-`rm` OSes, like Windows, so it's much safer to use `sbt.IO.delete` method.

Since it's about deleting files, there's the `clean` task that relies on `def doClean(clean: Seq[File], preserve: Seq[File]): Unit` method (from `sbt.Defaults`) and with proper changes it could also be of some help. I think it would require a new config, though.

See [How to exclude files in a custom clean task?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24020437/1305344) for some guidance regarding a custom `clean` task.

Comment: I've implemented the answer, above, and works perfectly. I am now looking into your expansion, so I thank you for this as well!